# Does String::from_utf8_lossy() allocate memory?

Tags: rust

I want to convert the first 10 bytes of an array to a string.

If I do `String::from_utf8_lossy()`, this will return `&str`.

Do I understand correctly that `&str` is the address of those 10 bytes and in fact the memory will be allocated only to create the link?

Comment: There may be some confusion here because `String::form_utf8_lossy()` returns a `Cow<str>`, not a `&str`. Docs [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy); as they say, the function does not allocate if no replacement characters need to be inserted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting from [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy) for `String::from_utf8_lossy`

> This function returns a [`Cow<'a, str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html). If our byte slice is invalid UTF-8, then we need to insert the replacement characters, which will change the size of the string, and hence, require a `String`. But if it's already valid UTF-8, we don't need a new allocation. This return type allows us to handle both cases.

So it doesn't return a `&str`, but rather `Cow<str>`, and only allocates if necessary to replace invalid bytes with "�".

In general, though, if a function actually returns `&str`, that `&str` won't be (newly) allocated. It'll either be static (embedded in the binary itself) or will have a lifetime derived from some argument to the function (e.g. [`String::trim`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.trim)).